# Are there any grammatical errors in the statement “As are you.”?

Tags: grammaticality, expressions

If someone compliments you, and you want to respond with the same compliment, Is it grammatically incorrect to say “As are you my friend."

Answer (score 3):

It depends on exactly how the compliment is phrased. If they say 'you are [adjective/noun/whatever]' then yes it is correct. 
So:
You are really kind!
As are you! :-)

But if somebody say something like 'I really like you', it wouldn't work, because 'as are you' basically means 'you are as well/too'. So a response to 'I really like you' could be 'likewise!'(slightly more formal) or 'same to you!' (a bit less formal).

The one thing I would say is that 'as are you sounds' a *little* elevated, and I would say '*so* are you' sounds a bit more natural.